# How to create a list within a list that could be accessed via keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to recreate the functionality I use a lot in lua programming, with python. I will demonstrate the lua code and explain what it does, as I do not know the official terminology of this programming behaviour.

In lua programming, you could write something like this:

```
luaTABLE = {
    ["green"] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 },
    ["blue"] = { 100, 101, 102, 103 }
}
```

This means that I have created a table (in python it would be a list) which has 2 subtables: "green" and "blue" and when accessing it I could say:

```
print(luaTABLE["green"][10])
>> 10
```

meaning, I am accessing table's subtable's element at possition 10

Now, is it possible to recreate this behaviour in Python, so that I could get something like:

```
pythonLIST = [
    ["green"] = [],
    ["blue"] = []
]
```

So that I could say something like:

```
pythonLIST["green"].append("some text for example")

for element in pythonLIST["green"]:
    print(element)
>>> 'some text for example'
```

Comment: In Python it would be a *dictionary*, not a list. I'd recommend reading a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
data = {
    "green" : [],
    "blue" : []
}
```